# mysql database foreign reference, delete not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I have a situation like shown below:

[image]

Here, I have two main tables A & B. with Primary Keys IdA and IdB.
Now I have a table C, where primary key is IdC, and colum IdB is actually a foreign reference to Table B (Id) with Cascade option.

Similarly, I have Table D with only two colums and both are references to table A and Table C.

So that IdA in D is referencing Id in Table A and IdC in table D is referencing IdC in Table C.

It works fine, such that if i delete an entry in Table C, it gets deleted from Table D.
Also if i delete an entry in Table A, it also gets deleted in Table D.

However what is not working, I can not delete an entry in Table D.
Atleast phpmyadmin does not allow me to do that. How can i do that. Because if i delete an entry in Table D. i don't wnat any other table to be affected by it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it was a very trivial issue, Table D did not have any primary key colum. After adding that, now i get the option to be able to delete any row i like